# Symmetrical of a triangle's vertexes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles, triangles

I have the following problem :

**Show that the symmetrical (ie reflection) of a triangle's vertexes by the opposite side are aligned iff the distance between the orthocenter and the circumcenter is twice the circumradius.**

---

I made a few pictures with GeoGebra to try and find a way to solve that, but it didn't really help.

When two of them ($A'$ and $C'$) are in the same place :

[image]

When they are distinct and aligned : [image]

Comment: I see that you [have created](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/964019/revisions) the tag ([tag:linear-system]). It is good practice to create also [tag-wiki and tag-exceprt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/linear-system/info) when creating a new tag, so that it is clear what the tag is intended for. (Some users even prefer that creation of a new tag should be discussed on meta first.)

Comment: Just by the name of the tag I could think that it is for system of linear equations. Such tag is not needed, since since we already have [(linear-algebra) and (systems-of-equations)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra+systems-of-equations).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh sorry, I'll change that. When writing that tag, I thought it already existed and hence hit 'space' without checking

Comment: Do you mean "the distance between the orthocenter and the circumcenter is twice the circumradius"? It looks as if the distance between the orthocenter and the circle is equal to the circumradius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First draw the lines through $A', B'$ and $C'$ parallel to $BC, CA$ and $AB$. These make a triangle $A''B''C''$ say. See the diagram below.

1) We prove that $A''B''C''$ is an enlargement of $ABC$ scale factor $4$ from the centroid $G$.

[image: Diagram 1]

It is easy to see that $BYZ$ is an enlargement of $BCA$ scale factor $2$ from $B$. Hence $YZ = 2CA$ and similarly for the other two sides. Also $BC=CY$ etc.

The quadrilateral $YC''XC$ is a parallelogram, so $YC''=XC$. Applying this to every side gives that $A''C''= 4AC$ etc.

Since the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect eachother, $C''C$ intersects $YX$ at its midpoint. And since $C''YX \cong CAB$ by SAS, it follows that $C''C, A''A, B''B$ intersect at the centroid, giving us our original statement that we wanted to prove above.

2) We know that $GH = 4GT$ for any triangle and that $T$ lies on circle $ABC$ (since $OH$ is twice the circumradius and because $OT = TH$). It follows from this and the enlargement that $H$ lies on circle $A''B''C''$.

[image: Diagram 2]

But now notice that $A'B'C'$ is simply the Simson line of circle $A''B''C''$ from $H$! Hence $A', B'$ and $C'$ are collinear, as required. The converse is simply this last step applied backwards, as the converse of the Simson Theorem is also true.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This might sound a bit stupid to you, but I don't really get why $BYZ$ is an enlargement of $BCA$ with a factor $2$. (I'm having trouble with the factor 2). This would arise really easily if we knew that one of the sides ratio was 2:1, but I don't see that anywhere. What did you use ?

Comment: Sorry about not making that clear! If you draw in $BB'$ intersecting $AC$ at $K$ say, then $BK = KB'$ by the definition of reflection. Then we see that $BKC \sim BB'Y$ in the ratio 2:1. Then the result follows.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/a3f733e02def6661b0936dfa8508a635.png can you please point out what I did wrong here ? $C''C$ etc don't go though $G$.

Comment: Your $G$ is not the centroid; $AA''$ is not drawn properly.

Comment: To find $G$ I drew the bisector of $CAB$ (line $j$) and $CBA$ (line $k$), is that wrong ? (btw I didn't draw $A''A$ at all)

Comment: Ah that is the incentre. The centroid is the point where all three medians concur; the lines that connect the vertices to the midpoints of the opposite sides.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17838/discussion-between-the-game-and-michael126).